# How to assembly in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

I'm trying to create a new project from scratch in assembler using Visual Studio 2010. I know I shoud tick masm in Build Customizations, but later I don't get Microsoft Macro Assembler in Project Properties window. Can someone explain me step-by-step how to create an assembler project from scratch and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Googling *how to create an assembly language program in "visual studio 2010"* coughed up [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271627/Assembly-Programming-with-Visual-Studio) on the first hit. Does that help?

Comment: I know that, I tried but failed. Every tutorial says like this. But this is the part that I don't get:
_Now (and if you skipped the last steps, this won’t work) right click on the Project and select ‘Properties‘. You should see a dialog like this (Note the MASM item at the bottom of the tree). If you don’t, then something went wrong._
I don't get MASM item in VS and don't know what do I do wrong.

Comment: Before that step, was the `masm` target available to be checked in the *Builds customization* dialog?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was the problem. I didn't have the target .asm file.